# Loading CSV causing error when adding edges to Networkx Graph due to additional commas

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx

Hi I'm working with Networkx to generate a network.

I have 2 CSV files, nodes.csv, and edges.csv

For nodes.csv, the columns are "Name" and "Type", so I have the following:

```
Name, Type
Gemini, System
EDD Case Management App, Module
```

For edges.csv, the columsn are "Source" and "Target", so I have the following:

```
Source, Target
Gemini, EDD Case Management App
```

Code I use to load the data:

```
with open('nodes.csv', 'r') as nodecsv:
    nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv)
    nodes=[n for n in nodereader][1:]

node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes]

with open('edges.csv', 'r') as edgecsv:
    edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv)
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader][1:]

edge_names = [e[0] for e in edges]
```

When I print `node_names` and `edges`:

```
['Gemini, System', 'EDD Case Management App, Module']

[('Gemini, EDD Case Management App',)]
```

I am getting an extra comma in `edges` which is causing downstream errors when I load edges data into the Networkx Graph

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3dbbe371ce6c> in <module>
      1 G.add_nodes_from(node_names)
----> 2 G.add_edges_from(edges)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py in add_edges_from(self, ebunch_to_add, **attr)
    950             else:
    951                 raise NetworkXError(
--> 952                     "Edge tuple %s must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple." % (e,))
    953             if u not in self._node:
    954                 self._adj[u] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()

NetworkXError: Edge tuple ('Gemini, EDD Case Management App',) must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.
```

I'm new to Python and Networkx

How do I remove the additional comma?

Comment: `('Gemini, EDD Case Management App',)` has only one element. The first comma is inside the string literal. the second comma is so its different from an simple expression inside parentheses

Comment: When you look at the data, Gemini is the Source, and EDD Case Management App is the target, so it should be just one element, because that is the only Edge in the data set so far; I'm not understanding why the additional comma is added

Comment: its not an additional comma, its just a tuple with one value. To write a 1 value tuple you must put a comma at the end so python knows its a tuple. `(1)` is just the same as `1`, but `(1,)` is a tuple with one element. The reason you see the extra comma is because its showing you the repr value(IE the expression to recreate this object) and thats how you write a one value tuple. if you check you will see its only got one item not 2. The comma is just for syntax and not actually part of the object its self

Comment: Thanks, I guess following the Networkx documentation, I thought I was folloiwng the guidance: Each edge given in the container will be added to the graph. The edges must be given as as 2-tuples (u,v) or 3-tuples (u,v,d) where d is a dictionary containing edge data.

Comment: Tried a bunch of different combinations and I do not know how to generate a 2 tuple or 3 tuple with the data set i have..

Answer (score 0):

For others that run into this problem.

After trial and error, restructuring the edges.csv file, by assigning Source to Col A and Target to Col B, solves the error